# How to boot from ubuntu live usb with 'try ubuntu' directly?

Tags: boot, live-usb

I created an Ubuntu 10.10 live usb with persistence feature. And it works well on my PCs. But one thing annoys me is that each time I boot from live usb, I have to choose between "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu". Is there any way to dismiss that dialog and boot directly to the live Ubuntu system?

Comment: +1 from me. I'd love to hear a solution to this. My laptop's hard drive is dead, so I've been doing everything on a USB drive with persistence, and it would be wonderful to bypass this step at startup.

Comment: Why don't you install Ubuntu directly on usb

Comment: @Achu: a Live Session + casper-rw file/partition has its uses... read-only system files, no login screen (or password for sudo), untouched clean install files (no need to keep ISO for install in another PC), etc. I always keep one in all my pendrives

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wouldn't do it the way you have, but it kinda depends what you want to use the USB key for. If you want to use it to do installs on computers then the way you set up the key is right. If you want to use it as a standard desktop install, that you can use on any random (or even just a few specific) machines then use this method instead:-

For this you will need:

- 1xUSB key onto which you will install Ubuntu
- 2xCDR or DVD or USB key onto which you will put the installer
- 1xComputer which is capable of booting off the above device

Steps to install:

- Download the ISO and burn it to a CD or DVD, or use USB startup disk creator (or unetbootin) to make an 'install USB key'
- Insert the above media into a computer and boot from it
- Choose 'Install Ubuntu' from the menu
- Once booted to the installer, insert the USB key you want to install Ubuntu "persistent" onto
- During the installer, when you get to partitioning, ensure you select the USB key inserted, to install Ubuntu onto.

  - Meaning, don't mistakenly install Ubuntu onto the internal hard disk on the computer
- At the end of the install you need to tell the installer to put GRUB onto your USB key, and *not* to overwrite the bootloader on the hard disk (or indeed the USB stick you installed from - I have made that mistake!)
- Once the install is done, you can shutdown, pull out all the keys and optical disks, and take that new key to any machine and boot from it.

Advantages to this method

- It's a full desktop install that you can add packages to, remove packages from and generally fully customise as you would any install
- You can enable encryption of the home directory during install so that if you lose the key you don't have to worry about losing your data

Disadvantages to this method

- It's not as straightforward as making a persistent key, but it's no more difficult than a standard Ubuntu install
- A full install on a usb flash key will cause more write cycles, and thus more wear and tear on the flash drive's memory, potentially causing it to fail much sooner

Comment: Yeah, I should have already tried that. Thanks :)

Comment: I found one problem with this solution. The USB disk cannot be formated in FAT format, which means it cannot be used in Windows system. Kinda inconvenient...

Comment: The main problem with this solution is that you cannot use it to install Ubuntu in another PC.

Comment: You cannot use it to install Ubuntu anymore, and it uses MUCH more space than usual persistent install - 3,5Gb instead of 700mb.

Comment: Sure you can, get a bigger USB stick :)

Answer (score 8):

You can remove 'ubiquity' package, it should remove the switcher but removes the ability to install the system from that USB as well.

There's one more way: on boot of live USB there's a purple screen with keyboard = accessibility symbols in the bottom. If you press any key while it's shown, you'll get another boot menu, which allows to boot directly to the desktop, bypassing the switcher. It doesn't remove the switching completely, but at least works much faster.

Comment: It does works a LOT faster. I use this myself... but its still annoying. I wish there was a way to bypass that and still use it as a Live Session (dont want a full install on USB)

Comment: There should be some way to make it automatically do this each time. Just need to figure out which config file is responsible for selecting the default option...

Comment: I was looking around, and a possibly better solution is to only remove the `ubiquity-frontend-gtk` package, not `ubiquity`. That way, you can still install it by selecting it from the boot menu, but it can't start the installer window.

Comment: Using `sudo apt-get purge ubiquity*` does not remove the switcher and, also, it doesn't boot in "try" mode anymore.

How you remove ubiquity?

Answer (score 7):

So far, I've been able to boot straight to my maverick netbook remix persistent live USB log in screen by edited the syslinux.cfg file on my USB drive.

1. Plug your live USB, go to syslinux folder on it.
2. Open txt.cfg (*better use a code editor like notepad++*), & copy the first five line.
   The code looks like this on my maverick netbook remix :

   > default live
   >   label live
   >   menu label ^Run Netbook Remix from USB
   >   kernel /casper/vmlinuz
   >   append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-netbook.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz splash --
3. open syslinux.cfg, & change it's content with the code you've copied before. You can delete `menu label ^Run Netbook Remix from USB` or you can change it like this `say Run Netbook Remix from this USB`
   (*basically you can put any line as long as you use `say` in front of it*)
4. save the changes you've made on syslinux.cfg, & we're done.

*note : backup the original syslinux.cfg in case the method I explained above is not working for you.*

Comment: I've used this several times. I would never have been able to work it out for myself. You are awesome :-)

Answer (score 2):

I a Kubuntu 14 live usb bypass 'Try it' by changing the following in the syslinux folder:

- Renamed syslinux.cfg to syslinuxOLD.cfg
- Copied txt.cfg as syslinux.cfg
- In the new syslinux.cfg 'append' line I removed the option ' maybe-ubiquity '

The first boot option now reads:

```
default live
label live
menu label ^Start Kubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi
append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
```

It now reboots directly to Kub 14

Answer (score 1):

**Another Simple Method to loose Try / Install**

I usually use a USB with a Full install on it. It is no use for installing Ubuntu but a Full install is more secure, makes more efficient use of disk space and is more stable, among other things. Nowadays use "something else" when partitioning, or it is easy to overwrite the hard HDD. I also like to make the first partition either FAT32 or NTFS for use as a Linux / Windows Data partition.

Editing the Syslinux file, as previously mentioned is also a good way to get rid of Try / Install. For 18.04 use **/casper/vmlinuz** not **/casper/vmlinuz.efi**.

An easy way to remove the Try / Install stuff on a persistent drive, is to go to System Settings, and set yourself up as a new administrative user. The Try / Install will disappear, you will be able to assign a password, and the drive can still be used to install Ubuntu.