# Live ubuntu Usb help

Tags: live-usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bypass “Try it / Install” screen when booting from USB Live Session? (without installing in the USB)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47522/how-to-bypass-try-it-install-screen-when-booting-from-usb-live-session-wit)

I have a live ubuntu usb. how can i do for boot automatly in "try ubuntu without installing"

Thanks

(it's a bootable usb ubuntu 11.10)

Comment: just check this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/32484/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-live-usb-with-try-ubuntu-directly for reference

Comment: Have you booted with it yet?

Answer (score 0):

First Boot into your USB and the ubuntu options will be displayed on ur screen. First it will ask to choose ur language (default is English) after that select try ubuntu without installing. ENJOY . **Note** Their Could Be some Lag bcoz its booting from usb / CD /Dvd.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have made the USB bootable and not just copied the ISO image in the USB.

Once you are sure it is bootable,Plugin the USB and boot(make sure your boot sequence is set to USB first)

After booting successfully, you will get the 1st screen to appear like this-

[image: try]

Click on the **Try Ubuntu** option and you will be logged in to run Ubuntu live to experience it..!!

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you did make your usb the right way, it could just be that your motherboard does not support booting from usb. You can check this in the BIOS.