# How to reset configuration for Compiz for another user?

Tags: unity, compiz, configuration, root, users

After modify something in cssm the display manager in `MyPersonalAccount` doesn't work.

So I login in my root account and it is fine but I want to reset the Compiz configuration of `MyPersonalAccount` to default, as I can't even open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> in `MyPersonalAccount`.

How can I reset the Compiz (cssm) configuration **for a specific user** from the root in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: i put the user name of mine ,but gives me this user isnt existed , is there any command gets me all usernames of all useraccounts from the root terminal ?

Comment: `man 5 passwd;more /etc/passwd`

Comment: @Ahmed: all users should have their own folder in /home/. If you do `ls /home/` you should be able to see all users registered on the computer.
Perhaps you need to do `sudo ls /home/` instead, but I expect not.
@Lucio: I'd upvote that as an answer, can you put it down as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucio has a perfectly valid answer in the comments, I think, that would be a good approach. This is more a backup should his approach not work. There is another thing you could try: logging in as the default user on the tty terminal and removing the Compiz configuration files there.
Note that you should be able to return to the default interface at any time by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F7</kbd>

Boot your computer and continue till where you get stuck. Try logging in to the first tty by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>. Log in with your normal user and password. Then try what Lucio suggested: `cd /home/USER/; rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .compiz-1 .config/compiz-1 .config/dconf`.

If you can remove those folders but it does not help, you might want to try to reset the Unity profile completely. For that in Ubuntu 12.10, follow the answer given by Mahesh in [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

To reset the configuration of the Compiz Config Settings Manager or *ccsm* you must enter the following command in a terminal:

```
cd /home/USER/; rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .compiz-1 .config/compiz-1 .config/dconf 
#replace 'USER' with the account that you want to resolve
```

I recommend you to enter the above command from your [root account](https://askubuntu.com/q/92379/62483) entering into a [tty](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=833765) or from a [Ubuntu Live Edition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32484/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-live-usb-with-try-ubuntu-directly), doing `chroot` over your system ([follow steps 1 to 5 here](https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/62483)) from a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/62483).