# Booting from Live USB without typing "live"

Tags: boot, live-usb

Can I set "live" as the default option so that I don't have to type it each time I boot the PC?

Can the config file below be changed somehow to achieve it? Currently it looks so. I've never changed it before.

```
$ cat syslinux/txt.cfg
default live
label live
menu label ^Start Kubuntu
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed boot=casper maybe-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label check
menu label ^Check disc for defects
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append noprompt boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash ---
label memtest
menu label Test ^memory
kernel /install/mt86plus
label hd
menu label ^Boot from first hard disk
localboot 0x80
```

It's Ubuntu 16

Please, mark this question as duplicate of [How to boot from ubuntu live usb with 'try ubuntu' directly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32484/how-to-boot-from-ubuntu-live-usb-with-try-ubuntu-directly)

The answer that worked for me was
https://askubuntu.com/a/865314/572615

Comment: You type `live` on every boot????

Comment: DPP: "Duplicated" post, first answer is no good if the OP wishes to use USB to install Ubuntu. other answers using syslinux.cfg apply to UNetbootin installs only. UNetbootin Linux no longer works with 18.04. other installers use text.cfg or txt.cfg, often found in the Isolinux folder. Please do not call obsolete posts duplicates, it is not a service to the readers.

Comment: @ka3ak : An easy way to disappear the Try/Install stuff is to go to System Settings, and set yourself up as a new administrative user. The initial interrogation will end, you will be able to assign a password, and the drive can still be used to install Ubuntu.